# logical operator inside for loop, not working

Tags: python

I'm currently studying Python and I've been stuck at this problem for a few hours now. I was given a task to take user input of numbers and split those numbers, and display numbers greater than 3, example:

```
Input: 12345
Output: 4
        5
```

I had some progress with splitting those numbers, and now I'm at this part where it's supposed to figure out if the number is greater than 3 but I keep on getting "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' "

Anyway, here's my code:

```
num_input = list(input('Enter number: '))

for i in num_input:
    if num_input > 3:
        print(i)
```

Comment: if i>3:   should come

Comment: Change your code to `if int(i) > 3:`.  The error occurs because you are using the `>` operator on the list and python does not know how to compare a list of numbers with a number.

Comment: You will have to convert your list items to an `int` to do a proper comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it should be:

```
num_input = input('Enter number: ')

for i in num_input:
    if int(i) > 3:
        print(i)
```

Basically, you just get a single char from the string `12345` at a time and convert it to an `int`. Then you can compare it to 3 normally.

If you need a shorter version:

```
num_input = input('Enter number: ')

print([int(i) for i in num_input if int(i) > 3])
```

Which you output: `[4, 5]` if you input `123456`

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the objects inside the list as integers and then only you can compare them to an integer, in your case greater than three. This should work

```
num_input = list(map(int,input().split()))

for i in num_input:
    if i > 3:
        print(i)
```

This allows to input multiple values in a single line

Comment: Man, I use that code and type in 123456 and it just output 123456

Comment: for multiple inputs you have to use space between them. If you want to pass from 1-6 you have to give input like this- 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: Ok it does work if I use 1 2 3 4 5 6

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `list()`. Your input is string, you can iterate through every character of string, cast it  to int and then compare:

```
num_input = input('Enter number: ')

for i in num_input:
    if int(i) > 3:
        print(i)
```

Comment: btw There is no `casting` in python. Your example is of a conversion.

Comment: Explicit type conversion is also called `casting`

Comment: To be honest I don't get you. You just write total offtopic based on semantics and then argue "you are the only right here" without providing any informations. Just google the conversion and casting difference. I did the job for you and here is first random link https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/type-conversion-and-casting

Comment: I'm saying that only other people call it `casting` because there is such a thing in other languages. Python is so strongly typed that you cannot 'cast', you can only convert and python.org doesn't mention it.